# Depending on the order of my JOIN columns, I receive the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

To begin with, I don't have administrator access to our database.

I'm writing a simple query to combine some data from two separate tables. My query will either work or fail depending on the order I join the columns.

The error I get is:

> An error occurred while executing batch.
> Error message is:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The data is identical and I'm joining with the exact same criteria. That *should* mean that regardless how the query is filtering the tables, it will end up at the same conclusion.

I just don't understand why it works one way but not the other.

Example query which causes error:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [dbo].[Table1] as T1
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Table2] as T2 ON T1.[Store No_] = T2.[Store No]
                         AND T1.[Transaction No_] = T2.[Transaction No_]
                         AND T1.[Terminal No_] = T2.[Terminal]
```

Example of working query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [dbo].[Table1] AS T1
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Table2] AS T2 ON T1.[Store No_] = T2.[Store No]
                         AND T1.[Terminal No_] = T2.[Terminal]
                         AND T1.[Transaction No_] = T2.[Transaction No_]
```

Comment: Try running outside of SSMS, eg with SQLCMD.  This looks like a .NET exception.

Comment: is this the exact query that you used ?